# Help adding string inside alert view

Tags: iphone, string, nsstring, uialertview

I have a sting that is equal to a text field that i want to insert inside of a UIAlertView.

```
NSString *finalScore = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:[counter2 text]];

UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                initWithTitle:finalScore
                                message:@"You scored X points"
                                delegate:self
                                cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];

[myAlertView show];
[myAlertView release];
```

I want to replace"X" with the score from the string "finalScore"

I know how to have it just with the score, you would simple just enter the strings name without quotes under the message section, but i want the the text there too along with the string.

Thanks a bunch,
Chase

Answer (score 4):

Replace your `message:` parameter with:

```
message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"You scored %@ points", finalScore]
```

Also, note that your original code for `finalScore` uses string formatting without any arguments, which is either a no-op or unsafe (if it contains a `%` symbol). You are also leaking your `finalScore` object.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like the following, and pass it as the `message` variable to UIAlertView's initialization:

```
NSString* message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You scored %@ points",
                              [counter2 text]];
```

You might have to change some details about the formatting string depending on the type that comes out of `[counter2 text]`, however, though the above should work in many of the cases you'll encounter.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
@"You scored X points"
```

use:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"You scored %@ points", finalScore]
```